# XStream: De-serialise XML element containing attribute and child elements of same name

Tags: java, xml, xstream, xml-deserialization

How can I successfully de-serialise this using XStream?

```
<MyElement name="abc">
    <name>foo</name>
    <value>123</name>
    <name>bar</name>
    <value>456</name>
</MyElement>
```

I've tried the following, but the 'name' attribute does not get de-serialised and I end up with null for that property. If I rename either the attribute or child 'name' element to something else (for test purposes - I don't have control over the real data source), it works OK.

```
public class MyElement {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String name;

    @XStreamImplicit
    @XStreamAlias("name")
    List<String> paramNames;

    @XStreamImplicit
    @XStreamAlias("value")
    List<String> paramValues;

    ...
}
```

I tried using this form for the name list, but XStream gives me a 'Duplicate field name' exception. (Incidentally, either form works fine for the 'value' list.)

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="name")
List<String> paramNames;
```

Lastly, I tried creating a custom converter as follows, but then ran into an entirely different problem, whereby the reader cannot give me the attributes of my top level element. Instead, when I use any of the reader.getAttribute* methods, it gives me information on attributes of the next child node instead of the current node! (But that's a different matter.)

```
public class MyElementConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class type) {
        return MyElement.class.equals(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object arg0, HierarchicalStreamWriter arg1,
            MarshallingContext arg2) {
        // Not used, so no implementation
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
            UnmarshallingContext context) {
        MyElement myElement = new MyElement();

        myElement.setName(reader.getAttribute("name"));

        myElement.setParamNames(new ArrayList<String>());
        myElement.setParamValues(new ArrayList<String>());

        while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            if ("name".equals(reader.getNodeName())) {
                myElement.getParamNames().add(reader.getValue());
            }
            else {
                myElement.getParamValues().add(reader.getValue());
            }
            reader.moveUp();
        }

        return myElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many questions, try to follow the example http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html

Comment: The question at the very top is my focus. I've reviewed that tutorial on a number of occasions, but will take another look to be sure.

Comment: Nothing in the tutorial explains the peculiar attribute handling behaviour I am seeing in the converter. At any rate, that is not the thrust of the question. If there is a way to resolve this problem without a converter, that is preferable.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: Too long ago sadly... not in that job anymore so don't even have access to the source to check!